# error when moving code from VC++6 to VC++2008

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++

I am creating a **VC++2008 Windows Form Application** which needs to use some of classes from our **VC6** project.

When I added one file which contains the following method:

```
bool Property::createPaths(string &sPaths)
{
    char *tok = NULL;
    char seps[] = "\\";
    string str;
    if (sPaths.size() > 0)
    {
        tok = strtok((char*)sPaths.c_str(),seps);
        str  = tok;
        while (tok != NULL)
        {
            int res = CreateDirectory(str.c_str(),NULL);
            tok = strtok(NULL,seps);
            if (tok != NULL)
            {
                str += "\\";
                str += tok;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

I got error complain the **CreateDirectory** call:

***error C2664: 'CreateDirectory' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'const char *' to 'LPCTSTR'***

Searched online, seems I need some configuration on my VC2008 project to fix this. Anybody can tell me where and how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passing a `const char*` to a function expecting a `TCHAR*`.

`TCHAR` is defined as either `char` or `wchar_t` depending on the compilation settings - and by default in VC2008 it is `wchar_t`. Your use of `std::string` assumes that `TCHAR` is `char`, which causes the error you see.

There are two reasonable fixes available to you:

- In your project settings, change `Configuration Properties/General/Character Set` to `Use Multi-Byte Character Set`.

Or

- Refactor your code to account for the potentially different definitions of `TCHAR` - you'd start this by replacing any use of `std::string` or `std::wstring` with `std::basic_string<TCHAR>` (using an appropriate typedef) and wrap string literals in the `_T` or `_TEXT` macro.

Comment: +1, Ten minutes with no answer so as I'm writing one up you beat me to it.